# how to release resources of a process

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, process

I am invoking an external process by using System.Diagonistics.Process and passing two filenames as parameters. Now some time this process terminates due to exceptions and it seems that files handle are not being released by the process. How can i release the resources occupied by the process.

Answer (score 1):

What is making you think that file handles are not being released? Since you are starting a process which is external to your application you don't have much control over what the other process is going to do when it terminates abnormally.

Comment: For my case it was COM port. If user remove `USB-to-Serial` interface physically, the process crashes, however the file handle for it stays open and subsequent access to port all will fail. the only work around for this is restarting computer or removing driver and installing it again with most of the time because the port stays in use, windows selects another port to install the interface. this happens even in same process, so still need a way to release the handles.

Answer (score 1):

This application is WMVAppend.exe (available with Microsoft Media SDK). Even when we restart the machines, it report the error dialogue and work fine for the next run. The issue with only media appending which is not done by our process. I also checked the source files and they seem perfect but they are not appended perfectly and files are not available to use.

Or It might be possible that process is not terminated at all, but i am using Process.WaitForExit() which should return only the process is terminated. The error dialog on restart suggests me this case could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting that file handles are not being released by the dying process?

All resources should be released by a process that dies for any reason. If they aren't, then it is a bug that should be filed with Microsoft.

Comment: How is that Microsoft's bug? The OP is starting a process external to his application that then subsequently terminates abnormally. If that process opened file handles then it's that processes responsibility to close them correctly.

Comment: The OS is responsible for closing any handles that remain open when a process terminates.